# Display an absolute block in the background of another absolute block

Tags: html, css, properties, position, absolute

I would like to know if there is a way to put an absolute block B1 in the background, so that another absolute block B2 can be in the foreground on a part of B1.

Example :

10 pixels occupied by B1 : B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1B1;

8 pixels occupied by B1, 2 by B2 : B1B1B1B1B2B2B1B1B1B1;

Of course, in that special case, there are easy other ways to do it. I'm in a case where I would really B1 and B2 to be absolute... so, does a property enable to do that?

Comment: Still can't see B2 :) PLease, use a JSFiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.b1{position:absolute;
    z-index:1;}
.b2{position:absolute;
    z-index:2;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try "z-index" property of CSS.